What is the difference in aiohttp default Content-Type vs requests module's defaults?
I am working with an API that requires RSA256 public key POSTed as bytes. I was using requests (at first for testing) and aiohttp (to scale it up for many requests) and noticed a difference that I am trying to understand.
I have posted examples using httpbin for reproducibility, and a random generated public key.
When making a request with requests like:
import requests
headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer blah"}
resp = requests.request(
    method="POST",
    url="https://httpbin.org/post",
    verify=False,
    headers=headers,
    data={"my_public_key": b"""-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA6OOwyUe1h6HMIzrtcudQ
v7uoCbvLnFIa1ZeITiFc2NeeeIoZGAmjHd1nunaNTBXF3mfENedJh/qDAojv56UK
rUggHm0DUsiUov9HxTkyOsIhNkKuhR/dzMyEp+J1nYjQN0cuD1hBHwULADdi5kpe
37rYBPiSu63cG58weiLezfP8FyjBy3Yu+dnlqdLvFtgoDbcGvyCWZKPQsjUOiDzD
T98My7+GpF3bOJDE4tly7qns1fWK2a4HZKFMLcYKySWr4wysPIa22nG6R01hEfuw
94HXnVKMUSsLcHFhd6Q24xoykKAch4XozWbIxz9xkCEqs/EHxQ8KMOD0K7Nkzads
/QIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"""}
)
print(f"data: {resp.json()}\n")
print(f"response headers: {resp.headers}")

I would receive an "unsupported content type" error. This led me to needing to use a files parameter and io.BytesIO() on the bytes() string to receive success like this:
import requests
import io

headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer blah"}
file={"my_public_key": io.BytesIO(b"""-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA6OOwyUe1h6HMIzrtcudQ
v7uoCbvLnFIa1ZeITiFc2NeeeIoZGAmjHd1nunaNTBXF3mfENedJh/qDAojv56UK
rUggHm0DUsiUov9HxTkyOsIhNkKuhR/dzMyEp+J1nYjQN0cuD1hBHwULADdi5kpe
37rYBPiSu63cG58weiLezfP8FyjBy3Yu+dnlqdLvFtgoDbcGvyCWZKPQsjUOiDzD
T98My7+GpF3bOJDE4tly7qns1fWK2a4HZKFMLcYKySWr4wysPIa22nG6R01hEfuw
94HXnVKMUSsLcHFhd6Q24xoykKAch4XozWbIxz9xkCEqs/EHxQ8KMOD0K7Nkzads
/QIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----""")}

resp = requests.request(
    method="POST",
    url="https://httpbin.org/post",
    verify=False,
    headers=headers,
    files=file
)
print(f"data: {resp.json()}\n")
print(f"response headers: {resp.headers}")

However, using aiohttp This would work without any issues.
import aiohttp
headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer blah"}
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    async with session.request(
        method="POST",
        url="https://httpbin.org/post",
        headers=headers,
        data={"my_public_key": b"""-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA6OOwyUe1h6HMIzrtcudQ
v7uoCbvLnFIa1ZeITiFc2NeeeIoZGAmjHd1nunaNTBXF3mfENedJh/qDAojv56UK
rUggHm0DUsiUov9HxTkyOsIhNkKuhR/dzMyEp+J1nYjQN0cuD1hBHwULADdi5kpe
37rYBPiSu63cG58weiLezfP8FyjBy3Yu+dnlqdLvFtgoDbcGvyCWZKPQsjUOiDzD
T98My7+GpF3bOJDE4tly7qns1fWK2a4HZKFMLcYKySWr4wysPIa22nG6R01hEfuw
94HXnVKMUSsLcHFhd6Q24xoykKAch4XozWbIxz9xkCEqs/EHxQ8KMOD0K7Nkzads
/QIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"""}, 
    ) as resp:
        data = await resp.json()
        print(f"data: {data}\n")
        print(f"response headers: {resp.headers}")

So, my question is, how are these methods differing when sending bytes objects via an API call?
From what I can see, both libraries auto-generate Content-Type headers based on the data being passed in, but I still see different behaviors in result.

Just view the actual request by sending it to nc -l 8000 (on Ubuntu, it's in the netcat-openbsd package) or something similar.
